# Play playlist or track by permalink not trackid

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

I have an embedded player that works by trackId but:

1. I but I am trying to get non-technical users to embed the tracks or playlists into pages.
2. I sometimes need to regenerate the playlists

For both these reasons it is inconvenient that the player needs trackId. Is there a way I can play off the permalink?

Thanks,
   Martin.

PS. My current iframe code looks like this:

src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Fplaylists%2F$paramPlaylistID"

This iFrame code (from Comment #1) doesn't work:

src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http://api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Fplaylists%2F$paramPermalink"

Is there something better I can use? I recognize that I may need to do something to the url=...url= but I'm not clear whether resolve works with this player or whether the answer only applies to if I'd made a custom player.

Thanks again, M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [SoundCloud's API docs on `resolve`](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#resolve):

> The resolve resource allows you to lookup and access API resources when you only know the SoundCloud.com URL.
>
> ```
> $ curl -v 'http://api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json?url=http://soundcloud.com/matas/hobnotropic&client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID'
>
> < HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
> < Location: http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/49931.json
> ```
>
> This request will resolve and redirect to the API resource URL for the track http://soundcloud.com/matas/hobnotropic. Just follow the redirect and you will get the representation you want. The resolver supports URLs for:
>
> - users
> - tracks
> - playlists (sets)
> - groups
> - apps

You can take a the permalink from a user and get the track or playlist ID like so:

```
function getSoundCloudId(permalink, callback) {
  var resolve = 'http://api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&url=';
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (this.readyState === 4 && this.responseText) {
      var response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      if (response.id) callback(response.id);
    }
  };
  request.open('get', resolve+permalink, true);
  request.send();
}
```

Then you use it like so:

```
getSoundCloudId('https://soundcloud.com/matas/sets/library-project', function(id){
  // Do stuff with the ID
  console.log(id);
})
```

Comment: Ok, so I've moved the iframe code above as I'm too limited in this box. Suffice to say that I am not really using the API in this case, just the embedded player in an iFrame. Is this still workable? Can you give me an example? Thanks kindly. M.

Comment: Thanks @idbehold - so, will that work with w.soundcloud.com/player?

Comment: @MartinCleaver I've created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z6tbj/) for you. Paste in a playlist/set permalink and click "Get Embed Code" to see it in action.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate that! Looks good - now just waiting for my colleague to test it. Best, M.

Comment: @idebehold - actually we do have a further issue on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19440040/soundcloud-api-origin-mysite-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin - thanks, M.