# Soundcloud API - Origin <mysite> is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

As a follow-up to [Play playlist or track by permalink not trackid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19351797/play-playlist-or-track-by-permalink-not-trackid/19352075#19352075): the solution provided works fine seemingly everywhere except Safari on Mac.

On the Safari on Mac we see 
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.soundcloud.com/playlists/.json?client_id=..., Origin  is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

This is somewhat complicated by the fact that we have embedded the JavaScript into another site (Confluence). The standalone fiddle worked fine on Safari.

From [XmlHttpRequest error: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595515/xmlhttprequest-error-origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin) I suspect the problem is something to do with jsonp, but really this is out of my expertise.

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks, Martin.

Comment: Could you please specify the exact URL you are trying to load?

Comment: Sure - the code is at http://jsfiddle.net/cadalso/dFYvL/ - thanks. M.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using the JSONP approach. Here's an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z6tbj/1/) using JSONP instead of XMLHttpRequest. The main difference is in the `getSoundCloudId()` method and the addition of a global `jsonpResponse()` method.

```
function getSoundCloudId(permalink) {
  var jsonp   = document.createElement('script');
  var script  = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  jsonp.type  = 'text/javascript';
  jsonp.async = true;
  jsonp.src   = 'http://api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json?client_id='+CLIENT_ID 
              + '&url='+permalink+'&callback=jsonpResponse';
  script.parentNode.insertBefore(jsonp, script);
  return false;
}
```